# Can I run audio signals through a dimmer switch to control volume?

Tags: audio, dimmer

I have long had a off/on light switch in my living room controlling whether the speakers in that room are on or off. More recently, I've wanted the music in the living room to be slightly softer than that in other rooms. I've thought about replacing the light switch in there with a dimmer switch, but I don't know if decreasing the voltage of an audio signal is safe, or functional to decrease volume. Is it? If not, what are some other solutions?
Thanks,
-A

Comment: If you replace "dimmer switch" with a volume pot which fits in the same space and looks similar, then yes. A dimmer switch as is - no.

Comment: No. A dimmer switch that is built to dim lights cuts off parts of the mains sine wave to decrease the "average voltage". Applying this to music would sound terrible if it works at all.

Comment: No, but if your audio signal is high enough amplitude to keep the SCR conducting, it might make an interesting fuzz box/distortion generator!

Comment: @ALX - If your amp/"receiver"/whatever allows it, you could also choose to lower the output to that "Zone" through the "Levels" or "Equalizer" function. This would apply an offset to keep that room slightly lower than the other. That method of course is not convenient if you want to quickly change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

[image]

*Figure 1. Dimmer switch triac phase-angle control waveform.*

Dimmer switches work using a triac to control the *mains* voltage. The turn-on point in the mains half-cycle is varied to reduce the effective voltage.

- The dimmer works with mains voltages. Your audio will only be around 10 V or so.
- The dimmer works with constant mains frequency and amplitude. Audio signals vary in both frequency and amplitude.
- Chopping a music signal in such a way would produce awful distortion.

Other solutions:

- A stereo wirewound potentiometer. This needs to be rated for the power of your system and isn't a great solution.
- Separate amplifiers per room.
- Fixed resistors which can be switched in and out.

Answer (score -2):

Yes u can!!!!! I have had one on our upstairs speaker by the kids bedroom for yrs now. If she goes to bed and the stereo/surround on we can either dim it down or we can turn it rt off.

Comment: That's not a dimmer switch then. Can you supply a make, part number and, ideally, a link to a datasheet?